# custom exceptions what() returns "std::exception"

Tags: c++, exception

Here I've just build a custom exception but after throwing and catching it the what method of the exception does not return the reason as it should. instead it is just retunring "std::exception".

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class CustomException: public std::exception {
  public: std::string m_reason;
  CustomException(std::string reason): m_reason(reason) {}
  const char * what() {
    return m_reason.c_str();
  }
};

void
function () {
  throw CustomException("no reason");
}

int main() {
  try {
    function ();
  } catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to figure out that the what method was missing the `const noexcept override` annotation to correctly override the `what` method of std::exception class with the signature `virtual const char* what() const noexcept;` (since C++11)

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class CustomException: public std::exception {
  public: std::string m_reason;
  CustomException(std::string reason): m_reason(reason) {}
  const char * what() const noexcept override{
    return m_reason.c_str();
  }
};

void
function () {
  throw CustomException("no reason");
}

int main() {
  try {
    function ();
  } catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: just always specify `override` when overriding, and save the time

Comment: `const noexcept` was necessary to correctly override, and `override` is optional to help you realize it does or does not correctly override

Comment: and fwiw, `const` is sufficient to make it override rather than hide the method from the base, but it then still needs `noexecpt` https://godbolt.org/z/W3rnM6M4P. Nice example of how a change in the language not breaking old code leads to more quirks